# Многосточный поиск без использования флагов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, search, netbeans

Задача - заменить многострочные комментарии в NetBeans IDE.

```
/**
text
*/
```

Вот так бы могло работать:

`#\/\*\*.*?\*\/#s`

Но я не нашел, где в NetBeans можно добавлять флаги к регуляркам.
Перечислять все возможные символы - не вариант.

Многострочные - имеется в виду не сам тип комментариев, а то, что они содержат переносы строк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как в нетбинсе, но в phpStorm для поиска многострочных комментариев отработала такая регулярка: `\/\*\*[\s\t\n]*.*?[\s\t\n]*\*\/`

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, отлично работает.